# PYQT4 NameError global name 'ui' error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I am a newbie pyqt4 learner and i am a facing a problem while linking .py files with each other

```
def sigwin(self):
    self.signUpWindow = QtGui.QDialog()
    self.ui = Ui_Dialog2()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.signUpWindow)
    self.signUpWindow.show()
```

this is coding of my main.py file which is a window with a sign up button when i click on sign up it gives me error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 40, in sigwin
self.ui.setupUi(self.signUpWindow)
File "/root/folder/abc/sign.py", line 80, in setupUi
a.clicked.connect(ui.signwin)
NameError: global name 'ui' is not defined
```

my main file is linked with sign.py file on which i think its giving me problem on the function which is linked with another file

```
def signwin(self):
    self.welcomeWindow = QtGui.QDialog()
    self.ui = Ui_Dialog1()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.welcomeWindow)
    self.welcomeWindow.show()

  a=self.pushButton
    a.clicked.connect(ui.signwin)
```

this a=self code is the signup button linked with signwin

its giving me error of global ui idk how to solve this

hope it helps

Comment: The indentation in python is important, please correct.

Comment: Also `self.ui` is different to `ui`